# Getting an error while trying to apply the labels of geom_text to a subset of bars

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-text

I want to apply geom_text to a particular set of variables.

I have, for example:

```
  decade   count
   <dbl> <int>
1   1930   505
2   1940   630
3   1950   806
4   1960   446
5   1970   469
6   1980   807
7   1990  1057
8   2000  1856
9   2010  2133
```

My plot looks like this:
[My plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YkZ14.png)

So, I want to add some labels to each bar, where the year has to be shown. For the bars with a value of >= 500, I want the label to be inside the bar, for the rest I want it to be outside.

I tried to do this with geom_text:

```
geom_col(fill = THISBLUE,
           width = 0.7) +
  geom_text(data = subset(data, count >= 500)
            aes(0, y = name, label = name))
```

However, I get this error message:

`Error in count >= 500 : comparison (5) is possible only for atomic and list types`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this approach?

```
ggplot(df,aes(decade,count)) +
  geom_col(fill = "blue", width = 4) + 
  coord_flip() + 
  geom_text(data = subset(df, count >= 500), aes(label = count),nudge_y = -100,color="white") + 
  geom_text(data = subset(df, count < 500), aes(label = count),nudge_y = 100,color="black")
```

[image: bar_chart]

Input:

```
df =tribble(
  ~decade,~count,
  
1930,   505,
1940,   630,
1950,   806,
1960,   446,
1970,   469,
1980,   807,
1990,  1057,
2000,  1856,
2010,  2133
)
```

Comment: I was trying to use the function count() instead of the variable, your response helped me realize it.